# Elastic NEST Filter on Aggregations

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Ive now successfully got my c# Test win forms app working with aggregations and now I want to be able to filter on said aggregations if someone selects one (or more) of them.

Here is my query that is working exactly as I want and I am getting both price range buckets and buckets for each of the specification terms that it can find in the index.

```
.Aggregations(a => a
            .Nested("specifications", n => n
                .Path(p => p.ProductSpecification)
                .Aggregations(aa => aa.Terms("groups", sp => sp.Field(p => p.ProductSpecification.Suffix("name"))
                    .Aggregations(aaa => aaa
                        .Terms("attribute", tt => tt.Field(ff => ff.ProductSpecification.Suffix("value"))))
                        )
                        )
                    )
            .Range("price_range", ra => ra
                .Field(p => p.Price)
                .Ranges(
                    r => r.To(50),
                    r => r.From(50).To(100),
                    r => r.From(100).To(150),
                    r => r.From(150).To(200),
                    r => r.From(200).To(250),
                    r => r.From(250)
                    )
                ))
        .Index("myindex")
        .Type("product")
        .Query(q => q
            .MultiMatch(m => m
                .Query(searchBox.Text + "*")
                .Fields(ff => ff
                    .Field(f => f.Name, boost: nameBoost)
                    .Field(f => f.Description, boost: descriptionBoost)
                    .Field(f => f.ProductCode)))));
```

Can someone point me in the direction of how I can go about filtering down results based on selecting any of these buckets.

UPDATE (30/01/18) I have now added this to my query

```
&& q.Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.ProductSpecification)
            .Query(q2 => q2
                .Terms(t => t
                    .Field(f => f.ProductSpecification.Suffix("name"))
                    .Terms("Guarantee",)
                    )).Query(q3 => q3
                        .Terms(t2 => t2
                            .Field(f2 => f2.ProductSpecification.Suffix("value"))
                            .Terms("3 years","10 years")
                            )))

                    ));
```

This is enabling me to pass multiple values into one Spec filter, but what im not sure on how to achieve is how to filter on multiple specs so the above filters on Guarantee with values of either 3 or 10 years 
but if I also wanted to pass values of "Grey" and "Copper" to the spec of "Colour"

Adding "Colour" into My first set of terms and "Grey" and "Copper" into my second terms list breaks all filtering.
I think im close here just need a little direction

Comment: I have updated the question to include my progress on filtering the query, if anyone can give me any pointers to move ahead with this.that would be great

Comment: I have found how to solve this i will update with a full solution asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, when the user selects a price range from the price range facets that are applicable to the query that is being executed, you'd like to apply this price range to the query?

The [`Post Filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html) serves this purpose, by applying a filter to the search results *after* aggregations have been calculated.

Assuming a user has selected the 50-100 price range, your query would like something like

```
var response = client.Search<Product>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Nested("specifications", n => n
            .Path(p => p.ProductSpecification)
            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                .Terms("groups", sp => sp
                    .Field(p => p.ProductSpecification.Suffix("name"))
                    .Aggregations(aaa => aaa
                        .Terms("attribute", tt => tt
                            .Field(ff => ff.ProductSpecification.Suffix("value"))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .Range("price_range", ra => ra
            .Field(p => p.Price)
            .Ranges(
                r => r.To(50),
                r => r.From(50).To(100),
                r => r.From(100).To(150),
                r => r.From(150).To(200),
                r => r.From(200).To(250),
                r => r.From(250)
            )
        )
    )
    .Index("myindex")
    .Type("product")
    .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(m => m
            .Query(searchBox.Text + "*")
            .Fields(ff => ff
                .Field(f => f.Name, boost: nameBoost)
                .Field(f => f.Description, boost: descriptionBoost)
                .Field(f => f.ProductCode)
            )
        )
    )
    .PostFilter(pf => pf
        .Range(r => r
            .Field(f => f.Price)
            .GreaterThanOrEquals(50)
            .LessThan(100)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thats even better than the convoluted solution I had come up with Thanks Russ

Comment: One other question @Russ Cam for the ranges can this be generated automatically eg I always want 6 options but it will change dependant on the prices of the returned product eg it would be as above if the most expensive item is say 300 but if the most expensive item is say 1000 the ranges might be 0-200 200-400 400-600 600-800 800-1000

Comment: I don't know of a way of auto generating the ranges, without at least knowing the min and max of the data that match the query. Would you want to change the ranges though in this way? Would that not make the UI confusing? Would a slider work better here?

Comment: Our current interface is similar to this http://www.argos.co.uk/browse/technology/video-games-and-consoles/xbox-one/xbox-one-consoles/c:30029/?tag=ar:shop:xbox:consoles is there a way that I can get the min and max values and then build the range from them

Comment: Ive done a separate query and pre build the ranges based on the max beforehand